# What is the bot in Facebook for Developers' Object Debugger?

Tags: bot, facebook-developers

Do you know what bot that read websites' metadata from Facebook for Developers' [Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fqu%E1%BA%A3c%E1%BA%A7u.com%2Fcon-mat-lanh-nhu-bang%2F)? Perhaps the name is shown in wireshark, but since I have no root access to any server, I'm unable to know.

<sup>Related: [How to know what bots of a website, if I have no root access to the hosting they will read?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57591971/3416774)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Facebook Crawler - Sharing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler/):

> The Facebook crawler can be identified by either of these user agent strings:
>
> `facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)`
>
> or
>
> `facebookexternalhit/1.1`

See also: [Link Sharing FAQ](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/faq/)